# How do I conditionally uninstall shared object (Merge Module) files in WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a common merge module  as a part Wix installer MySetup1.msi, that should always deliver files and install service, but should only uninstall the merge module files/service when a condition is met. The condition is that common files should be uninstalled only when specific property is passed.
The merge module is also part MySetup2.msi.

I understand this can be done by using same GUIDs across components or using merge modules, but
MySetup1.msi should not uninstall merge module component, expectional case module can be uninstalled if specific FLAG is passed or else merge module should be uninstalled via MySetup2

Here little complexity, as we have shared component with common GUID, MSI installer service keep reference for shared object
If we skip to uninstall in MySetup1.MSI, I think one ref count will be pending.
And on MySetup2.msi uninstall this file will not deleted as there will be always refcount 1.

Any hints clue really appreciated,
I know reference counts kept at registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\Component
but bit skeptical about manipulating reg entries.

Here is code snipped where I am merging this module in original installer, but unfortunately did not worked any help really appriciated.

```
<Feature Id="MyMergedFeature" Title="My Merged Feature" Level="0" AllowAdvertise="no" Absent="disallow">
<MergeRef Id='MyModule' />
  <Condition Level="0">
    <![CDATA[REMOVE ~<> "ALL"]]>
  </Condition>
</Feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding the question.  What you should know though is that merge modules don't exist once they are merged into an MSI.  They are simply components associated to that feature. If a merge module is shared between two installers then they are simply shared components.

The condition element with a level of 0 simply hides the feature from being displayed in a first time install or change operation.  From my InstallShield days I think I recall a rule that says if you set it to 0 it could get orphaned and never uninstalled.  I'm not sure about that part without testing though.

I suspect your overthinking this.  Component reference counting will leave the components installed until the final product is removed by default.